# Trying to create a script to look for pods in '0/1' status for more than 20 mins or an hour and delete them

Tags: kubernetes, devops

```
 BAD_PODS=`kubectl get pods --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} | grep "0/1" | awk {'print $1'}`
if [ -z "$BAD_PODS" ]; then
    log "No Pod in Not Ready state"
else
    for pod in $BAD_PODS
        do
            duration=`kubectl get pod --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} $pod | grep "0/1" | awk -F' ' {'print $5'}`
            if [ `echo $duration | egrep "h|d"` ]; then
                log "Pod not running since more than an hour. Deleting it."
                kubectl delete pod --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} $pod
            elif [ `echo $duration | awk -F'm' {'print $1'}` -gt 20 ]; then
                log "Pod not running since more than 20 minutes. Deleting it."
                kubectl delete pod --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} $pod
            fi
        done
fi
```

this however does not seem to work when I deploy to my cluster. I keep getting a crash loop back off error. Would like some feedback in this

Answer (score 0):

Try command like

```
kubectl --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} delete pod $pod
```

whole script

```
BAD_PODS=`kubectl get pods --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} | grep "0/1" | awk {'print $1'}`
if [ -z "$BAD_PODS" ]; then
    log "No Pod in Not Ready state"
else
    for pod in $BAD_PODS
        do
            duration=`kubectl get pod --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} $pod | grep "0/1" | awk -F' ' {'print $5'}`
            if [ `echo $duration | egrep "h|d"` ]; then
                log "Pod not running since more than an hour. Deleting it."
                kubectl --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} delete pod $pod
            elif [ `echo $duration | awk -F'm' {'print $1'}` -gt 20 ]; then
                log "Pod not running since more than 20 minutes. Deleting it."
                kubectl --context ${EKS_CLUSTER_NAME} delete pod $pod
            fi
        done
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Harsh ! I tried it out but still no luck. I keep getting an error and it  eventually shows up as a crashloopbackoff error.

Comment: Check the logs what error are you getting ?